# Palm leaf creation

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a tropical island environment in unity, so for that purpose I want to model a palm. I want the whole scene to have a cartoonish look and feel to it, so I am going for something like this:

[image]

What I'm struggling with is how I can make the leaves. Does anyone have a link to a tutorial on how to make leaves such as these?
- I can't make the leaves bend as they do here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you have tried so far

Comment: I just don't know how to do it. I don't know where to start. Do you have any tips on how to model the actual leaf?
- As we can see on the picture, the leaf's lowest point is the middle line, so I guess I would have to have a straight edge from the beginning of the leaf to the very tip. Right?

Comment: Start with some beginner tutorials, learn basic modeling methods, UV unwrapping, texture painting, basic modifiers and the most important thing, use google before asking question. There are tons of tutorials about foliage, leaves, trees and other nature creations. Come back here with specific and detailed questions. For your last question, how to bend them, I would suggest using B-bone. It will allow to have nice control over the leaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a plane. Scale it into a rectangle which would fit the leaf inside of it. Select one end edge and scale it to 0 to make it a point. Then do on loop cut down the centre. Then do about 4 or 5 loop cuts down the middle. Select the edges each of those loop cuts made. [image: Loopcuts]

Press ctrl b to bevel and increase the segments to 2 and increase the offset to the size you want the bit where the leaf goes in to be.

[image: Bevel]

Go on by one grabing the mid points of each bevel and moving it inward to make in in bits of the leaf.

[image: moving mid points]

Turn on proportional editing and set the fall off type to sharp. Drag up and down vertices until you have the curve of the leaf.

[image: curve]

Merge the end points [image: selecting center]

Select the edge loop which goes from top to bottom of leaf. Disable proportinal editing and then grab it and move it down a bit on the z axis.

[image: moving on z]

Then add a solifiy modifer to make the depth of the leaf and you are finished.

Finished Result:  [image: Finished] [image: Finished]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to bend geometry is to use the Bend operator - <kbd>Shift-W</kbd> in Edit mode, with the relevant geometry selected. The 3D Cursor position on the screen is important.

Comment: Right then, I just tested the bend operator and it works great.

- But how would I go about modeling the leaf in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

What I wold do is: Start with doing the outline of the leaf (a 2D plane). Keep in mind you have to leave a grid-like topology for the surface of the leaf, and avoid using n-gons, or this will complicate things later. Then apply the solidify modifier to give it some thickness. after that you can use proportinal editing to bend the leaf in a smooth/natural way

Comment: What do you mean with grid-like topology?

Comment: that the faces that form the leaf are all quads (four vertices), and about the same size. In short, don't just do the outline and fill it with F, try to leave a nice structure in the middle.

Comment: Right, I just don't see how I'm going to do that.
- I've been using blender for a while, but i'm not very skilled..
I looked up at couple of examples on how to make a nice topology, but I don't see how I can transfer that to my model.